# Do you think it's possible for video content to be encoded in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming

I know how this will sound.

I couldn't help asking this question after looking at http://www.chromeexperiments.com/

Any ideas on possible implementation approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Video encoding is a relatively mature field now. Applying known methodologies to JavaScript would simply mean dumping impractical amounts of partial images and keyframe data as raw binary blobs in a JS file. There are no characteristics of JavaScript that would offer any advantage, or even parity, with existing methods.

That's not to say, of course, that new methodologies will not be developed. But I am highly doubtful that the future creator would post them for free on a website :)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the hard part is finding a suitable method of displaying the graphics, rather than the encoding. It's not really in the style of, say, canvas, to offer a raw memory address where you can dump graphics.